# Excel finding best mix of product placement in a shelf

Tags: python, excel

In Excel,

Lets say i have found the best rank for a given product and i need to find the best possible solution of mixing the products with a constrain, there can only be 6 of a unique item, and a max of 15 for all the possible combinations and there must be at least one of them, i know that, for the example i am presenting you can infere that the best combination is. 6+6+1+1+1 for the rank 1 to 5, but this excersise is really helpful for big datasets.

Thank you in advance and if there is a way to do this in python i would be glad to hear it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuzYl.png)

[Image tiny example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ptfZ.png)

Comment: This might be a good starting resource: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming

Comment: Of course. Perhaps a) https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-programming-and-discrete-optimization-with-python-using-pulp-449f3c5f6e99  and b) https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html.

Comment: May I ask you what is the rank? i will be thinking in prices or similar

Comment: I would suggest using `solver` add in - its pretty good at linear programming problems with multi constraints -  ive used it successfully on 200+ variable problems without havig to go to lpsolve

Comment: excel solver comes bundled with office, caters for continuous, binary and integer variables and you can find it under the excel add ins button on the excel developer ribbon. Once installed its on the insert ribbon.

Comment: @JohnnieL I find the Solver is on the Data ribbon and also on the Data menu drop down but not insert... unless you customised it...

Comment: @RafaelValero The rank is the Contribution Margin Per Meter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems need to be rewritten to have the appropriate  mathematical structure. In particular considering the way to solve. I will use `linprog` function so best to see their examples and information [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html).
Instead of a, b, c, d, e I will use x1, x2, x3, x4, x5.

This is because with the notation of the function could be confussing.
Adapting an example to our case:

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
A = [[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]]
b = [-15]

x1_bounds = (1, 6)
x2_bounds = (1, 6)
x3_bounds = (1, 6)
x4_bounds = (1, 6)
x5_bounds = (1, 6)

res = linprog(c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b,
        bounds=[x1_bounds, x2_bounds,
        x3_bounds, x4_bounds,
        x5_bounds],method='revised simplex')
```

The output looks like:

```
print(res.x)
[6. 6. 1. 1. 1.]
```

*Interpretation*: Best option is to pick 6 of a, 6 of b, and 1 of each of the rest.

**References**

1. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html
2. https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-programming-and-discrete-optimization-with-python-using-pulp-449f3c5f6e99